# Почему в `swing` по умолчанию приложение не завершается при нажатии на крестик?

Tags: java, swing

Почему в `swing` по умолчанию приложение не завершается при нажатии на крестик?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что так определено в JFrame:

```
private int defaultCloseOperation = HIDE_ON_CLOSE;
```

Comment: почему так определено?

Comment: @user232141: Ну как-то ж надо было определить? Вот разработчики подбросили монетку и решили.

Comment: @VladD это неочевидное решение, например, для пользователей windows, должны быть какие-то веские причины

Comment: @VladD в конце концов, можно было ввести неопределённое состояние

Comment: @user232141: Ну, неопределённое состояние хуже: состояние «по умолчанию» должно быть наиболее «правильным». Почему разработчики swing посчитали `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` самым правильным, наверное, знают только они.

Comment: @VladD согласен, что оно хуже, но ведь должно быть объяснение, почему так. Уверен, что взяли не случайно

Comment: @user232141: В WPF, например, по умолчанию `ShutdownMode=OnLastWindowClose`. Так что каждый фреймворк решает по-своему.

Comment: @user232141 обычно в программе больше чем одно окно. прятать окно при закрытии более эффективно, чем завершать программу.